# Help understanding math notation

Tags: notation

What does the "^" represent in the statement below? It definitely doesn't mean to the power of as that makes no sense in this context. Thanks for the help!

Since X(t) is a pure death process with constant death rate , Y(t) can be viewed as a
truncated Poisson process below N, namely, Y(t) has the same distribution as **Z(t) ^ N** where Z(t) is a Poisson process with parameter theta.

Comment: What it says: $Z(t)$ truncated at $N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a very common notation, but generally A ^ B is sometimes used for shorthand for the minimum of A and B, so Z(t) ^ N is limiting values to be below N.